# Length of list as condition in any function for list comprehension

Tags: python, list

I want to use the length of my list for which I'm generating a list comprehension as a condition along with those in the list comprehension that is being passed to the any() function itself

I could do this in two lines -

```
li = [1,2,3,4]
lcond = [x for x in li if x > 3]
any(lcond) and len(lcond) >2
```

But I'd like to do it in one

Comment: *"I'd like to do it in one"* - why? Are you charged by the character? Write readable code!

Comment: Explicit is better than implicit. [Python Zen](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

Comment: What is `any(lcond)` for?

Comment: `len(lcond) > 2` *implies* that `any(lcond)` would be true.

Comment: @chepner my point :-)

Comment: Well initially this condition was among others in an if bracket. Writing it in two lines would require me to change things significantly. Initially my condition was if x and y and z, x being given above (minus the list length requirement). If there's a way to do it, it'd be more succinct.

Comment: @ReutSharabani Yeah, your comment didn't pop up until after I posted my comment.

Comment: @ReutSharabani Ah got it thanks.

Comment: @jonrsharpe See, it can be done in one line, succinctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't really need a list comprehension here.

```
if len(filter(lambda x: x > 3, li)) > 2:
```

In Python 3, you need to explicitly consume the generator returned by `filter`:

```
if len(list(filter(lambda x: x > 3, li))) > 2:
```

---

Actually, why am I even using `filter` here?

```
if len([x for x in li if x > 3]) > 2:
```

`any` is unnecessary, because a non-zero length of the list implies that `any(...)` would return true.

Answer (score 1):

If your list is a very large one I recommend you don't 
go through the whole list just for knowing if there are at least two items that satisfies the conditions.

I suggest to use islice from itertools applied over a generator like that:

```
test_list = [1,2,3,4]
# Returns False
len(list(itertools.islice(filter(lambda x: x>3, test_list), 2))) == 2

test_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
# Returns True
len(list(itertools.islice(filter(lambda x: x>3, test_list), 2))) == 2
```

It is more complex but if the list is huge it's better don't go through the whole list.